# How to enable fullscreen in IFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe

i am using iframe but fullscreen button is not working.

i have check inspect element i am getting below

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" src="https://videos.xyz" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe id="kaltura_player" src= “https://videos.xyz”  width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allow="autoplay *; fullscreen *; encrypted-media *" sandbox="allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-modals allow-orientation-lock allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-presentation allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation" frameborder="0" title="Kaltura Player"></iframe>
```

any solution to enable fullscreen

Comment: try using this <iframe allow="fullscreen;">

Answer (score 2):

To enable fullscreen on an `<iframe>`, use `allow="fullscreen"`

```html
<iframe allow="fullscreen"></iframe>
```

The `allowfullscreen` attribute is now considered as a legacy attribute and it's now redefined as `allow="fullscreen"`.

[IFrame Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Good hint but the new attribute is still not implemented for Firefox for Android